# How to get an image from gallery after application gets killed?

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, oncreate, ondestroy

I am developing an application which contains several fragments representing different screens. One of the fragments represents edit profile screen, where user can change his profile image. One of the options to change an image is to select image from gallery. To do so I use an intent to open a gallery.

```
action_chose_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

Once I open the gallery, my application goes to background and then gets destroyed due to low memory on my phone. This intent is being sent from within edit profile fragment. To maintain application state, I save string representing specific fragment in the Bunble within `onSaveInstanceState()` inside activity. When the activity is recreated, I check the bundle inside `onPostCreate()` method and add the right fragment to the activity.

```
 @Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "On post create");

        if (savedInstanceState.getInt(FRAGMENT_STATE)== MY_STATUS){
            state = MY_STATUS;
            displayMyStatus();
            footer.setSelected(MY_STATUS);
            footer.displayButtons();
        }else if(savedInstanceState.getInt(FRAGMENT_STATE)== TEAM_STATUS){
            state = TEAM_STATUS;
            displayTeamStatus();
            footer.setSelected(TEAM_STATUS);
            footer.displayButtons();
        }else if(savedInstanceState.getInt(FRAGMENT_STATE)== MY_PROFILE){
            state = MY_PROFILE;
            displayMyProfile();
            footer.setSelected(MY_PROFILE);
            footer.displayButtons();
        }else if(savedInstanceState.getInt(FRAGMENT_STATE)== EDIT_PROFILE){
            state = EDIT_PROFILE;
            displayEditMyProfile();
            footer.setSelected(MY_PROFILE);
            footer.displayButtons();
        }
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

When I open gallery my activity gets destroyed due to the lack of memory on my device. When I chose image from gallery my activity gets recreated and I add the right fragment the way I described above. However I am not sure what happens during activity recreation with the result I get from gallery.

I tried `onActivityResult()` methods, however it does not get triggered.I guess it must be triggered within exact same fragment from which the intent to gallery was sent.

My question would be:

What happens with image that was requested from gallery and how should I obtain it inside activity that has been recreated? Where can I find the image that was selected from gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by moving gallery intent to an activity class. Then `onActivityResult()` method is being triggered.